# JavaFX TextFlow set default text color

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-css, textflow

As the title, it's possible to to apply a default color to all text of a TextFlow component?

```
TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
textFlow.setId("supertextflow");

// Somewhere else in the code
textFlow.getChildren()
    .add(new Text("Dynamic added text! OMG!"));
```

I tryed different solution but none of them works

```
#supertextflow {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}

#supertextflow * .text{
    -fx-fill: red;
}

#supertextflow > * > .text {
    -fx-fill: red;
}
```

I know that Text is another component, but why i can't style it from it's parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can't do that with `Text` cause it's style class doesn't have fill css rule if you look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text). So I would suggest to leave the `Text` and use `Label` instead. If you do then you could use the css rule below :

```css
#supertextflow > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-font-size : 20px;
}
```

In case you want to keep using Text you will have to set each element (Text) inside the FlowPane a specific id (ex. #customText) and then use it to set the CSS rule like below :

```css
#supertextflow > #customText {
    -fx-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size : 20px;
}
```

**Edit :** As James_D mentioned on the commends below you should use **Type Selector** (I am guessing that's the correct term) on the CSS rule in order to style all the Text nodes inside your `TextFlow` without needed to set any ids on them :

```css
#supertextflow > Text { 
    -fx-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size : 20px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work with a type selector, i.e. `#supertextflow > Text { -fx-fill: red; }`, with no need to use labels and no need to set style classes or ids on the `Text` instances?

Comment: @James_D Oh yes! I thought I was forgetting something :P. Using `#supertextflow > .text` will not work but using `#supertextflow > Text` instead will do the trick. Thanks for pointing that out.